# Why don't my smart controls display any data?

Tags: sapui5

My SmartField in SmartForm doesn't render data in the UI. I don't understand why. SimpleForm with the same OData path in the input value works fine.

SmartForm in the view:

```xml
<smartform:SmartForm
  editable="true" 
  app:defaultCheckBoxDisplayBehaviour="OnOff"
  app:defaultDropDownDisplayBehaviour="idAndDescription"
  editTogglable="true"
  editToggled="handleEditToggled"
  layout="ResponsiveGridLayout">
  <smartform:Group>
    <smartform:GroupElement>
      <smartfield:SmartField id="zgutInputDescr" value="{ZGUT_CDS_UI5_CDS>Descr}">
        <smartfield:layoutData>
          <l:GridData span="XL2 L2 M2 S2"/>
        </smartfield:layoutData>
      </smartfield:SmartField>
    </smartform:GroupElement>
  </smartform:Group>
</smartform:SmartForm>
```

[image: Screenshot of my SAPUI5 SmartForm view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, Smart controls work with an unnamed model only. From the [topic "Prerequisites"](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/0e84ac7c9d3e4acaa49e61e6ee808649):

> The smart controls require a default OData model, and **named models are not supported.**

Hence, the issue was solved by deleting name of the model from the `manifest.json` and other places.

[image: Annotated manifest.json SAPUI5]

```xml
<!-- ... -->
  <smartfield:SmartField id="zgutInputDescr" value="{Descr}">
<!-- ... -->
```